# The element type 'VxAnimatedBox' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Here I'm trying to use VxAnimatedbox under scaffold but it's showing error

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body:Stack(children: [
        VxAnimatedBox().size(context.screenWidth, context.screenHeight)
      .withGradient(LinearGradient(
        colors: AIColors.primaryColor1,
        ))
      ],)
    );
  }
}
```

These are the 2 errors its showing

```
The element type 'VxAnimatedBox' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
The argument type 'Color' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Color>'.
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have written
`VxAnimatedBox().size(context.screenWidth, context.screenHeight)`, make sure you add `.make()`, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error it's telling you that the `LinearGradient` object is expecting a List, but you are passing just ONE Color.

You can fix it by putting that one color inside a List (and, if you want, add more colors to your liking)

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body:Stack(children: [
        VxAnimatedBox().size(context.screenWidth, context.screenHeight)
      .withGradient(LinearGradient(
        colors: [AIColors.primaryColor1],
        ))
      ],)
    );
  }
}
```